# Totally ordered set can contain exactly 2 elements?

Tags: relations, order-theory

I have 2 questions

1) Should totally ordered set always contain only 2 elements ?

I think that a poset with a single element is also totally ordered as it can be reflexive, anti-symmetric and transitive. Also it is comparable with itself.
My professor says that for totally ordered set you always need 2 elements (a and b) for comparison.

2) Are totally ordered set always complemented lattice ?

I think that there might be a totally ordered set which is infinite and infinite sets have no upper bound. So it's not complemented lattice

Am I correct?

Comment: I don’t think there’s anything wrong with a one point set being totally ordered.  Not useful at all, but not wrong.

Comment: "My professor says that for totally ordered set you always need 2 elements (a and b) for comparison." I guess that your professor means that you need 2 *variables* in the totality axiom. 2 variables can refer to the same element, formally, $a=b$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Indeed, a poset with just one element is not only totally ordered, it even is well ordered. Also note that the empty set with its only possible relation *also* is totally ordered (and well ordered).

   If that were not the case, the theory of ordinals would be in deep trouble. :-)
2. It is true that there are totally ordered sets that are infinite, but it is not true that infinite sets never have upper bounds. For example the real closed interval $[0,1]$ with the usual order is both totally ordered and infinite, but clearly has an upper bound (namely $1$).

   However it is true that there exist infinite totally ordered sets that do not have an upper bound; $\mathbb N$ is the simplest example of it.

Comment: So, a toset with n>2 can never be a complemented lattice right ? However with n=1, it is complemented lattice right ?

Comment: @Zephyr: I'm not sure whether the definition of a complemented lattice requires that $0\ne 1$. If so, then a complemented lattice would have to have at least two elements, and thus a single-element toset could not be one. If OTOH, there is no such requirement, then the single-element toset trivially is a complemented lattice with the only element being its own complement. A toset with more than $2$ elements can indeed not be a complemented lattice.

Comment: I think it would be a separate question to ask whether Upper bound and lower bound can be same .

Comment: In a totally ordered set then upper and lower bound both existing and being the same would mean precisely that there is exactly one element.  If a set has at least two distinct elements then a < b for some two elements and every upper bound is $\ge b$ and every lower bound is $\le a$ and there is no number that is both $\le a$ and $\ge b$ while $a< b$.  likewise if $x$ is both an upper and lower bound of a set then any element $a$ is that $x \le a\le x$ so $a=x$ for all elements of the set.

Comment: @fleablood Thanks for replying. Also can empty set be a complemented lattice ? I think it cannot be because there does not exist any lower and upper bound . Also smallest 'n' which is Boolean algebra would be for n=1 as it is both distributive and complemented right ?

Comment: One really shouldn't worry about vacuuos truth pedanteries.  An empty set does have lower and upper bound (any number is vacuously greater, less, and equal to all elements of the empty set) but it has no least or greatest element (there is not element of empty set that is equal or less than all elements).  My understanding of complemented lattice is that there is a partially ordered set (vacuously true), is bounded (vacuously true), every element has a complement (VT) and has a least and greatest element.  (FALSE!)  At least that's how I would argue.  In any event... It's vacuous.